# How to update script variable from imported module?

Tags: python, global-variables, python-import

Is it possible in python 2 to update global script variable from another module?

Here is simplified script example (**test_script.py**):

```
import sys
from test_module import test_function

variable = False


def main():
    test_function()
    print "script variable: %s" % variable
    print "sys.modules variable: %s" % sys.modules['test_script'].variable


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is simplified module example (**test_module.py**):

```
def test_function():
    import test_script
    test_script.variable = True
```

Here is script output:

```
> python ./test_script.py 
script variable: False
sys.modules variable: True
```

As you can see script variable has not been changed. Is it possible to change it? If yes, what code should I put inside test_function() to do it, without changing **test_script.py** itself?